# Make all CSS inline - Class Issue

Tags: php, html, css, inline

I found this [**awesome class**](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles/blob/master/css_to_inline_styles.php) that converts CSS style blocks to inline. However, I think it has a problem. For example, if you have the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
.myclass{
padding:0px;
}
<style>

<p class="myclass" style="padding-top: 40px;">Test</p>
```

It will convert the above to:

```
<p class="myclass" style="padding-top: 40px; padding:0px;">Test</p>
```

But the above is incorrect. It should prepend since the `padding-top` inline has priority as it is already inline. So it should be:

```
<p class="myclass" style="padding:0px; padding-top: 40px;">Test</p>
```

But I am struggling where to make this edit in the class. I thought it would be straightforward and I could submit it to the class creator but I am struggling.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would anyone want to have inline styles???

Comment: @Gordon for newsletter purposes or in-place content editing, for example.

Comment: @Gordon - many email clients, ignore style blocks including Gmail.

Comment: fair enough but thats about the only two things I can think of and at least the newsletter is due to poor standards in that field only. Might want to add that it's for a newsletter then though.

Comment: If this is about emails.. then i suggest you try this: http://premailer.dialect.ca/

Comment: @Lollero - its source is written in ruby. This is the only PHP alternative I could find.

Comment: @Abs did you tried hacking on it the way I told ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is [create an issue](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles/issues/new) and get in touch with the developer. So he can fix it for others too. That's a growth of the community .

Just going through the code in a quick way what I think is [before building the chunks](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles/blob/master/css_to_inline_styles.php#L318)  reverse the array $properties

```
$properties = array_reverse ( $properties, true );
// build chunks
foreach($properties as $key => $values)
```

The `$properties = array_reverse ( $properties, true )` which preserves the key on the top of build chunks on line 318 as linked will reverse all.

Hope that helps!
Not sure whether this will bring any other issues, just try.

Comment: it looks like it works with your change! Wow that is awesome! Going to test it some more.

Comment: Yes, it works for me! I found another issue with this class but I'll try solving it myself, if I can't I'll open another question. Thanks Hari! :)

Comment: Just so that everyone knows. The class has been updated by the owner and it can be found here: https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion

```
<p class="myclass" style="padding-top: 40px; padding:0px;">Test</p>
```

isn't wrong. because a inline-style overwrite a class-style

Comment: The above will equate to the p tag having a padding of `0px` -which isn't the case. It should have a padding-top of `40px`.

Comment: what i mean is: if u add a class to a p-tag that have already a inlinestyle. the inlinestyle still overwrites the class. the behavior is normal.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed in the latest version: see https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles